# Finding the appropriate stride for TLB misses in an array in a code snippet

Tags: c, arrays, operating-system, tlb, stride

Assume the system has a 32-entry TLB with a 8KB page size. What should MAX and stride be set to in order achieve a TLB miss upon pretty much every access to the array "data" ?

```
int value=0;
int data[MAX];
for (int j;j <1000; j++)
{
 for (int i =0, i<MAX; i+=stride)
 {
   value=value+data[i];
 }
}
```

This is a practice final exam which has answer but I don't get it. Final answers are :
stride=2k
MAX=33*stride

Any complete answer which will help me figure out how to find number of TLB misses in such type of questions is really appreciated.

Comment: There must be more information about the TLB that you haven't shared with us.  Page size, number of entries, associativity, etc...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stride=2k
```

This part of the solution is because ints are 4 bytes on the system in question. Since pages are 8KB, a stride of 2048 ints will place each access on a different page.

```
MAX=33*stride
```

Since the stride length is the page size, this sets an array length of 33 pages. Assuming the 32-entry TLB is full-LRU, that means that between accesses to a given page, all 32 other pages in the array are accessed, enough to evict the page from the TLB and cause a page fault when its turn comes again.